# How can i change a single tab in react native router flux tab bar?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

So i have a tab bar in my app which contains 3 tab i need to make socond tab completely different from others ( Circle shape with a plus in middle of it ), Now when i try to change the style of that single tab like raising the padding or margin it affects on all of them.
Any idea ?